# Loading swf Problem in Air,Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

I have 2 swf file, one file is loading fine in SWFLoader in Air application but another is not loading, i dont know why its happening. differents between two file :-

For ex:

Swf1 is Main swf .(it has dependency file like xml to read and render)
swf2 is Sub swf(which will load (or called) inside swf1 in run time) .

When try to load swf2 in flex3 air application using SWFLoader its working fine, but swf1 is not loading.
Swf1 is working fine individually in flash player 9.

But i need to load SWF1 only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, due to dependency file missing only i cant able to load it..now its loading fine..

But now i need to expose fscommand value from swf loader ....since i am getting some output from swf1 through fscommand when i click button in swf1 .. i need to get that fs command value.

i am using SWFLoader to laod swf1 ..